# Why doesn't H-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-H exist?

Tags: bond, stability

The question has its roots in why only carbon mainly shows catenation. I don't see why such a compound cannot be formed. Why don't we have a whole branch dealing with such compounds other than organic chemistry? If this compound can exist then such atoms will also be able to form a large number of compounds like the organic compounds.

Comment: Look at C-C and O-O bond strengths - and compare the O-O bond strength to that of O=O. Same goes for nitrogen (compare N-N single with N-N triple bond). Why can't you just have graphite-like layers of nitrogen?

Comment: Computationally it has been predicted that arbitrarily large $\ce{H2O_{x}}$ molecules are technically stable, though after more than a few they are presumably quite shortlived.

Comment: @Nicolau Saker Neto so you are saying that what sets carbon apart is its tetravalency and not catenation?

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Derek Lowe [posted](http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2014/10/10/things_i_wont_work_with_peroxide_peroxides) on peroxide peroxides. Seems the five-oxygen species is about as long a chain as you're likely to get, even if only fleetingly.

Comment: There are other elements which can catenate (boron and sulfur come to mind, iodine and mercury too in certain conditions), but carbon is pretty unique. I don't think any other element is expected to have a similar amount of covalent molecular chemistry

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto If one is willing to allow chains composed of multiple types of atoms, one can do decently well with $\ce{Si}$ and $\ce{O}$ -- e.g., the [siloxanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siloxane). (Though, even these generally use nicely stable organic carbon side/cap groups, as in [polydimethylsiloxane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydimethylsiloxane).)

Comment: @Brian Ah yes, some element combinations can go quite far. Silicon and oxygen are definitely a good match with rich chemistry. Sulfur and nitrogen also catenate well. Then there's transition metal polyoxometalates. Surely many other examples. [Here's a Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inorganic_polymer) which is quite relevant

Comment: A related, and surely under-upvoted, topic is [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15320/peroxide-linkages), dealing with the low strength of the peroxo bond. As well, [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/757/why-are-peroxides-explosive) addresses the thermochemistry of $\ce{H2O2}$ decomposition directly.

Comment: O is quite small. And it has lone pair and it has more tendency to go in -2 than in -1 state. It is like the second most electronegative element. Why?You know it better than me. Why do you think  such a compound would be stable? If it were we would already be studying about them. C on the other hand, has the best suitable properties for catenation.